# Clustering on thousands of product feature clicks and pages viewed

Tags: clustering, dimensionality-reduction, large-data, data-preprocessing

I want to classify 120k customers into 5-6 clusters basis the product usage, say, hundreds of product features clicked and hundreds of product pages viewed. The data will be like a customer_id has clicked feature_1: 500 times, feature_2: 300 times, etc., viewed page_1: 200 times, page_2: 300 times, and so on in a timeframe of 1 year. How can I reduce hundreds of features into a few relevant ones which can be fed in a clustering technique? What could be a few possible data pre-processing steps here? Can a sample (30k?) from 120k customers be representative of the population for the clustering exercise? Thanks!